# Java, addition error

Tags: java, runtime-error, addition

I noticed two days ago I had some weird strange issue with my lib transforming a mat4 (matrix 4x4, row major order) to a quat (quaternion) when I had 180° on z axes and 1° on x, all other values work just fine, that is 180° and 2° or 179° and 1° and so on..

After some deep debug, I found the issue

```
    double trace = 0, s, x, y, z, w;

    trace = m.c0.x + m.c1.y + m.c2.z + 1;
```

This should return trace = 0, given

```
m.c0.x -1.0
m.c1.y -0.9998477
m.c2.z 0.9998477
trace 5.9604644775390625E-8
```

But it doesn't... Why?

I found a temporary solution by calculating trace as the following:

```
    trace += m.c0.x;
    trace += m.c1.y;
    trace += m.c2.z;
    trace += 1;
```

Anyway I would like to know the reason in order to act accordingly in the future

Ps: I tried to convert it to double, they were floats before, but nothing changed. [Here](https://github.com/elect86/Jglm/blob/master/Jglm/src/jglm/Quat.java) the full code

Specs: Java 7 x64 on Win7 x64.

Comment: Floating-point types `float` and `double` are not infinitely precise. See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

If you work with floats or doubles, there is always a level of uncertainty involved, because their number ranges are not continuous. For absolute precision, you must perform calculations using BigDecimals.

Comment: And how, exactly, do you propose that OP performs trigonometric calculations using `BigDecimal`?  This answer is incorrect and unhelpful.

Comment: @DavidWallace OP's example uses simple addition: `trace = m.c0.x + m.c1.y + m.c2.z + 1;` This will work perfectly fine with `BigDecimal`.

Comment: No, OP linked to code containing sines, cosines, arctangents, and a few other bits and pieces that just don't exist in `BigDecimal`.  This is not just addition.

Answer (score -1):

just use the BigDecimal class  to calculate for the result. It will be right.

Comment: No it won't.  Not with trigonometric functions.  The only numbers that `BigDecimal` can store correctly are terminating decimals.  This answer is not correct.